# How to get Link button generated text inside repeater control

Tags: c#, asp.net, repeater

I am creating a social network site, I cant seem to get the "LinkEmail" in the code behind, I need this to function as I then use it to post to the database.

The `LinkEmail` is being dynamically generated in the first repeater, I need a way to grab that value.

at the moment I am getting this error in the browser:

Compiler Error Message: `CS0103: The name 'LinkEmail' does not exist in the current context`

this is aspx code

```
 <asp:Repeater runat="server" ID="Repeater1">
 <ItemTemplate>

     <div style="border-top: thin none #91ADDD; border-bottom: thin none #91ADDD; padding: 10px;  width: 548px; margin-top: 10px; right: 10px; left: 10px; border-left-width: thin; margin-left: 15px; background-color: #F6F6F6; border-left-color: #91ADDD; border-right-color: #91ADDD;">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                    <br />
                    <div style="width: 58px; height: 40px">
                    <asp:Image ID="Image2" runat="server" Height="59px" ImageAlign="Top" ImageUrl="~/Profile/Image/Default.png" Width="55px" />
                        </div>
                    <div style="width: 307px;  margin-left: 65px; margin-top: -60px">
                        <asp:Label ID="Label6" runat="server" Font-Bold="True" Font-Names="Arial" ForeColor="#3b5998"><%#Eval("YourName") %> </asp:Label>
                    </div>
                    <div id="status" style=" width: 461px; margin-left: 78px; margin-top: 11px;">&nbsp;<asp:Label ID="Label7" runat="server" Font-Italic="False" ForeColor="Black" Font-Size="Medium"><%#Eval("Birthday") %> </asp:Label>

                        <asp:LinkButton ID="LinkEmail" runat="server" OnClick="lbl_Click"><%#Eval("Email") %></asp:LinkButton>
                        <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button"  />
                    </div>

                    &nbsp;
                </div>


 </ItemTemplate>
```

Actually i want to get Link button generated text as a session like this [photo](https://scontent-a-ams.xx.fbcdn.net/hphotos-xpa1/v/t1.0-9/10676371_1504823446473898_7054992759456936682_n.jpg?oh=14f071a725eb3e737b205afc713d110f&oe=54FDAAF4) when someone click this link. could you give me a suitable codes for this.

According to this photo amilamunasinha@gmail.com must be LinkEmail.Text ,,, I want like this

Comment: Google asp.net linkbutton inside repeater control.  You will note answers handling the `ItemCommand` of the Repeater control.  You will also note that `CommandName` and `CommandArgument` attributes of the LinkButton control are also used.

Comment: how you are handling from code behined?

Comment: Actually i don't know, how write cs code for this. i am new to asp.net .

Comment: Take a look at this [`Repeater-Controls-ItemCommand-Event`](http://www.developer.com/net/asp/article.php/3609466/ASPNET-Tip-Responding-to-the-Repeater-Controls-ItemCommand-Event.htm)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first thing you have to do, once your `Repeater` control is on your Web page, is register for the `ItemCommand` event. I prefer to do this within the `OnInit` event of the page instead of placing it as an attribute of the `asp:Repeater` tag.

In .cs file:

```
override protected void OnInit(EventArgs e)
{
   base.OnInit(e);
   Repeater1.ItemCommand += new RepeaterCommandEventHandler(Repeater1_ItemCommand);
}



private void Repeater1_ItemCommand(object source, RepeaterCommandEventArgs e)
{
        switch (e.CommandName)
        {
            case "mail":
                string emailId = e.CommandArgument.ToString();
                break;
        }
}
```

In aspx:

```
<asp:LinkButton ID="LinkEmail" runat="server" CommandName="mail" CommandArgument='<%# Eval("Email") %>'><%#Eval("Email") %></asp:LinkButton>
```

Comment: Yes it's working, I don't know how to thank you, Thank you soooooooooo much